# Debugging gdb: exit code 139 in VSCode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-extensions

I am working on a large codebase and trying to debug the same using gdb(C/C++) extension on VSCode.
On running a particular configuration, I get an error with exit code 139. I know this is a segmentation fault, but am unable to exactly pinpoint where the seg fault is occurring. Is there any way I can monitor that?
Probably some file that I am missing where the details are being captured?

I can debug segfault using gdb from the terminal. But since the code requires certain configurations and is spread over hundreds of files, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Normally gdb would stop in the point of the code where the segfault occurred?

Comment: You should be able to see what the backtrace is in the integration. If you can find that you should be able to see exactly where the code crashes (i.e. the first non-bs memory location in the trace. I specify this because sometimes I get [?] 0x0 as first line)